# Use select-box value in the remote property (parameter) of Typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I have put together an application that makes use of **Typeahead.js** and a select-box containing American states.

As the docs show, the library has **[remote](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote)** property.

I want to add the value of the *selected option* of my select-box to `remote`:

```js
var chooseState = function() {
  var jud = '',
    stateChoice = $('.cm-state').find('option:selected'),
    stateText = stateChoice.text(),
    jud = stateChoice.val();
  console.log(jud);

  if (jud == '') {
    $('#display').hide();
  } else {
    $('#display').fadeIn(150);
  }
  $('#choice span').text(stateText);
  $('#choiceVal span').text(jud);
}

$('.cm-state').on('change', chooseState);

$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'typeahead',
  remote: 'search.php?key=%query&jud=' + jud,
  limit: 11,
  // My addition
  complete: chooseState
});
```

```html
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Choose State">
</div>

<div>
  <select class="cm-state">
    <option value="">- Choose state -</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="display">
  <p id="choice">State name: <span></span></p>
  <p id="choiceVal">State code: <span></span></p>
</div>
```

I get a **jud is not defined** error message instead.

Making the `jud` variable global with `window.jud = stateChoice.val();` does not solve the problem either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should fetch `jQuery` from cdn before fetching `typeahead`

Secondly, you are declaring `jud` variable inside the `chooseState` function, thus it can't be accessed from the `typeahead` init function on line `20` where you wrote the `$('input.typeahead').typeahead({`

Check the snippet below.

```js
var jud = ''; // declare 'jud' variable here, so it's global in the first place;
var chooseState = function() {
  // don't declare 'jud' here as it will become local variable for chooseSate function only;
  var stateChoice = $('.cm-state').find('option:selected'),
    stateText = stateChoice.text();
  // seperate jud from var declaration now, just update the global one;
  jud = stateChoice.val();
  console.log(jud);

  if (jud == '') {
    $('#display').hide();
  } else {
    $('#display').fadeIn(150);
  }
  $('#choice span').text(stateText);
  $('#choiceVal span').text(jud);
}

$('.cm-state').on('change', chooseState);

$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'typeahead',
  remote: 'search.php?key=%query&jud=' + jud,
  limit: 11,
  // My addition
  complete: chooseState
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery first, and then typeahead -->
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<div>
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Choose State">
</div>

<div>
  <select class="cm-state">
    <option value="">- Choose state -</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="display">
  <p id="choice">State name: <span></span></p>
  <p id="choiceVal">State code: <span></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid making the `jud` variable (or any other) global. I was hoping to be able to call the `chooseState()` function from within `typeahead` in a manner that would work, without "globalizing" `jud`.

Comment: you can put both `chooseState()` and `typeahead` on another function and call that function immediately after the page loads